# Split AC with diodes - missing current in opposite direction

Tags: current, diodes, ac

Here is my [circuit](https://www.multisim.com/content/U8qhFjra4mH88wujqBnQjt/split-oscillations/)

[image: circuit]

Here is output of measurements:

[image: va]

I cannot understand why there is no current in negative direction. Current keeps flowing in positive direction when there is negative voltage.

Comment: Because you have grounded it...?

Comment: You have a current flowing during the negative half-period. And the current is positive because of the way (the direction) you have connected the "green" ammeter.

Comment: Do you mean *no current flowing in negative direction* or *no current in negative direction of the voltage* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set both of your current probes to align with the diodes, rather than pointing to gnd.  As a result both currents appear to be positive.

If you change PR1 to point towards gnd, you will get the behaviour you are expecting.